# Get the total count of visible drodpdownlist and ids of all dropdownlist

Tags: jquery

I have a page and multiple `select` elements. Some are visible and some are not.
I want to get the count of visible `select` and their respective Ids.

I'm getting the count using `$("select:visible").length` but I'm not able to get the visible dropdown Ids.

Comment: You can either loop over that selector using `each()` or build an array of the `id` attributes using `map()`. You've not really told us *how* you want to retrieve the data, or *why* you require it so I can't guide you on which is more suitable in this case.

Comment: I want to validate that page, pass the ids of all visible dropdowns and their values to a ajax function. Please post a code sample related to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Count of visible dropdownlist:

```
var len = $("select:visible").length;
```

2) to get ids of all visible dropdown list:

```
$("select:visible").each(function(i,v){ // loop through all visible selectbox
   console.log($(this).attr("id")); // you can get id using $(this).attr("id)
   // OR
   console.log(this.id);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to validate that page, pass the ids of all visible dropdowns and their values to a ajax function

In this case it would be best to build an array from the `id` and values of the visible selects. You can do that using `map()` before sending the data in your `$.ajax` request, something like this:

```
var selectData = $("select:visible").map(function() {
    return { 
        'id': this.id, 
        'value': this.value
    }
}).get();

$.ajax({
    url: '/myendpoint',
    data: selectData,
    success: function() {
        console.log('It worked!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Rory. I'm calling ajax in a same way.